# Ethernet / Internet and Wi-Fi not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, ethernet

I am new to Ubuntu and I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and it is not detecting any Wi-Fi signals (which I can detect on Windows). Also, when I plug in the Ethernet cable, it doesn't show that Ethernet is connected even when the Ethernet cable blinks.

Here are the screenshots when I used `ifconfig -a` and `sudo lshw` commands on terminal.

[image]

[image]

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Either copy past that output from the terminal or use pastebinit rather then screen shots

Comment: alright , i will take care from next time, btw do you have a solution for my problem

Comment: copy paste the requested information here if you need help. In the terminal highlight the text with the mouse -> edit -> copy and paste it here with the code block, the { } button in the question.